# Laravel Eloquent whereDoesntHave() documentation confuses me

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Referring to https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence the query

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

$posts = App\Post::whereDoesntHave('comments.author', function (Builder $query) {
    $query->where('banned', 0);
})->get();
```

is described as "*retrieve all posts with comments from authors that are not banned*". This seems incorrect to me, as that seems to imply that if a post has one comment from a banned author and another comment from a non banned author, that post would be in the resultant collection - after all, it has comments from authors that are not banned.

In actuality, such a post would not be included in the collection due to the existence of a comment from a banned author, regardless of the other comments that post may have.

It seems more accurate to say "*retrieve all posts that have comments, none of which are from banned authors*".

Am I mistaking something?

Comment: its not just you, it seems off to me unless I am reading it wrong ... the docs are open to PRs ... but to me that example would read as I want all posts that do not have any comments from authors that are **not** banned. ... honestly i think i just confused myself writing that out

Comment: so i guess what i think that says is a Post has to have a Comment(s) only from Authors who are banned ...

Comment: @lagbox, yup, or no comments at all, submitted a PR to address per the below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, both are incorrect. it would be correct to say:

#### "retrieve all posts that have no comments, or where ALL comments are from banned authors"

I've created [this pull request for the Laravel docs to correct the wording.](https://github.com/laravel/docs/pull/6196)

The sql generated from such a call will look like this:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    `posts`
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS( SELECT 
            *
        FROM
            `comments`
        WHERE
            `posts`.`id` = `comments`.`postId`
                AND EXISTS( SELECT 
                    *
                FROM
                    `authors`
                WHERE
                    `comments`.`authorId` = `authors`.`id`
                        AND `banned` = 0))
```

Breaking that down, the inner query says "find me all the comments associated to each post, where that comment was written by an author that is not banned.

```
            SELECT 
                *
            FROM
                `comments`
            WHERE
                `posts`.`id` = `comments`.`postId`
                    AND EXISTS( SELECT 
                        *
                    FROM
                        `authors`
                    WHERE
                        `comments`.`authorId` = `authors`.`id`
                            AND `banned` = 0)
```

Then, the top level query says, "now, give me all posts where the above subquery returned no rows"

ie, all the authors were banned, or there were no comments at all.

```
  SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        `posts`
    WHERE
        NOT EXISTS(
          {.. sub query above here }
       )
```

---

## If you want to test this yourself,

Models:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;

class Post extends Model
{
    public function comments(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class, 'postId');
    }
}


<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne;

class Comment extends Model
{
    public function author(): HasOne
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Author::class, 'id', 'authorId');
    }

}

<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Author extends Model
{

}
```

Create table Sql:

```
CREATE TABLE `posts` (
    `id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
CREATE TABLE `comments` (
    `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `postId` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    `authorId` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    `content` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
CREATE TABLE `authors` (
    `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Content sql:

```
# crate a post
INSERT INTO `posts` (`id`) VALUES ('1');




# add a banned and not banned author 
INSERT INTO `authors` (`name`, `banned`) VALUES ('Jack', '0');
INSERT INTO `authors` (`name`, `banned`) VALUES ('Jill', '1');


# add a comment from a banned and not banned author 
INSERT INTO `comments` (`postId`, `authorId`, `content`) VALUES ('1', '1', 'a');
INSERT INTO `comments` (`postId`, `authorId`, `content`) VALUES ('1', '2', 'b');
```

Now run the code:

```
$post = \App\Models\Post::whereDoesntHave('comments.author', function ( $query) {
     $query->where('banned', 0);
})->get();
```

You'll get back 0 results.

Now run this to make both authors not banned:

```
UPDATE `authors` SET `banned`='0';
```

You'll still get back 0 results.

Now run this to make both authors banned:

```
UPDATE `authors` SET `banned`='1';
```

You will now get back 1 result.

Now run this to make both authors not banned again but delete their comments:

```
UPDATE `authors` SET `banned`='0';
DELETE FROM `comments`;
```

You will now get back 1 result.

This proves that the actual behavior is to "retrieve all posts that have no comments, or where ALL comments are from banned authors"

Comment: tested and confirmed. nice one.

Comment: Huh, that was my initial impression, but I screwed up my test case and so ended up with my incorrectly amended understanding of it haha. Nice one!

Comment: Hmm, I suppose this might be shortened to "Retrieve all posts that do not have comments from banned authors"? Since that would catch both the case for posts that don't have comments and for posts that have comments, but not from banned authors. Although your version is more documentation-appropriate I think, as it's exceedingly clear.

Comment: comment hasOne author relation: wouldn't that mean commentId is in authors table. For having authorId (author_id) foreign in comments table there should be comment belongsTo author. Difference between hasOne and belongsTo is where foreign key is set. Right?